# Android: 4 SD card permission

Tags: android, permissions, sd-card, file-access

I have application posted on play market , i always tested it on android 2.3 emulator , on phone SG s plus - cyanogen mod 9  android 4.0.4  , on S ace with 2.3.6 , and it worked fine , but when my friend downloaded it on HTC evo with android 4.2.2 she alway get an error . I starten on pc emulator of nexus 4 with android 4.2.2 and i got error:

> Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission
>   denied)

I dont know what to do , I have permission in manifest , and everything looks to be fine.
If anybody have same problem  , give me solution , or try if you have android 4+ my ap on your phone would it work or not . any help will be useful;

! I tried app on 6 phones and it dont work nly on 4.2.2; ! 
he is link to app  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cvs.hiddennote#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDIxMiwiY29tLmN2cy5oaWRkZW5ub3RlIl0.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>